# What ASP.NET MVC Route controls the appearance of hashes in URIs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have integrated a Silverlight Navigation Application in an ASP.NET MVC web. However when Silverlight calls for its default page, say, `IndexPage` ASP.NET MVC displays the route as:

```
http://localhost/#/IndexPage
```

I have tried to get ASP.NET MVC to respond to this route:

```
http://localhost/#IndexPage
```

but I am unable to find a configuration that works with this. Does ASP.NET MVC routes respond to hashes in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight's navigation system and ASP.NET MVC routes are completely separate here. The hash is a client-only thing and it can't be expected for ASP to reliably get that info.